# Write a function delchar(s,c) that takes as input strings s and c

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

> Write a function delchar(s,c) that takes as input strings s and c, where c has length 1 (i.e., a single character), and returns the string obtained by deleting all occurrences of c in s. If c has length other than 1, the function should return s.

I have tried this code but its printing in different lines. I want in one line. What the algorithm should be? Is my algorithm correct?

```
def delchar(s,c):
    
    if (len(c)==1):
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if (c is not s[i]):
                print( s[i])
            else:
                continue

delchar('banana','n')
b
a
a
a
```

> But I want the output in one line.

Comment: you are not `return`ing anything from the function, you are `print()`ing it, look up what `return` in a function means. Create a new list inside the function, and put each matching character in there. After you are done with iterating through the whole string, [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the newly created list together, and use `return` to get it back from the function. When you are iterating through the string, dont use `len(s)`, just `for letter in s:` should work, it gives you directly the character, you dont need to use `s[i]` to get the letter

Comment: I have added an answer and also improved your code. There is no need of continue.

Answer (score -2):

Write:

```
 print( s[i], end="")
```

instead of:

```
 print( s[i])
```

Actually when u use print, by default it adds a line break, so u have to use end="".

Full code:

```
def delchar(s,c):
    if len(c)==1:
        for i in s:
            if c!=i:
                print(i,end="")
    else:
        print(s)
        

delchar('banana','n')
```

Comment: Also note that you are trying to print not return. So I have also printed. Ok?